# Gráficos com HTML e CSS

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Alguém sabe se existe uma formar de fazer gráficos em barras ou linhas usando CSS e HTML?

Comment: Com o canvas, já fiz até jogo com direito a animações, personagens andando para cima e para baixo e lutando, sons e tudo mais. Gráficos de barras e linhas é moleza. Para ter uma ideia, veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99995/132

Comment: Dá para fazer com SVG também. Para ter uma ideia, veja essa pergunta que respondi há quase dois anos atrás: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58719/132

Comment: Veja esse exemplo: http://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/phiyL

Comment: @Taisbevalle Excelente esse link. :)

Answer (score 2):

Carlos, apesar de possível fazer do zero, você pode usar o d3js como ponto inicial para os seus gráficos.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
var data = [
 {"key":"Stream #0","values":[
  {"x":0,"y":0.14090541293475303},
  {"x":1,"y":0.18577189134868652},
  {"x":2,"y":0.17080494531362053},
  {"x":3,"y":0.11943955279666824},
  {"x":4,"y":0.12973567147943157},
  {"x":5,"y":0.14638145776456224},
  {"x":6,"y":0.16149379899349633},
  {"x":7,"y":0.13926904239580462},
  {"x":8,"y":0.1834697636052203},
  {"x":9,"y":0.17595684858191474},
  {"x":10,"y":0.2329394353357669},
  {"x":11,"y":0.5118096038931783},
  {"x":12,"y":1.0604245910128074},
  {"x":13,"y":1.933431270315826},
  {"x":14,"y":2.6860729715445872},
  {"x":15,"y":3.076926232520845},
  {"x":16,"y":2.6498994752803133},
  {"x":17,"y":1.8644784354019341},
  {"x":18,"y":0.9666636940028317},
  {"x":19,"y":0.5401218367797567},
  {"x":20,"y":0.27854949515284794},
  {"x":21,"y":0.16574099526914662},
  {"x":22,"y":0.118347820270082},
  {"x":23,"y":0.11664119595071204},
  {"x":24,"y":0.19678126522080203},
  {"x":25,"y":0.15486774367158815},
  {"x":26,"y":0.19992047674686325},
  {"x":27,"y":0.17490783895837436},
  {"x":28,"y":0.15495825192553067},
  {"x":29,"y":0.10433995600831547},
  {"x":30,"y":0.14669215112248235},
  {"x":31,"y":0.12447128914865549},
  {"x":32,"y":0.1192817679403776},
  {"x":33,"y":0.15624403631652425},
  {"x":34,"y":0.1893867054355094},
  {"x":35,"y":0.123245827602213},
  {"x":36,"y":0.18922970519604806},
  {"x":37,"y":0.2766569466840088},
  {"x":38,"y":0.31638815979932666},
  {"x":39,"y":0.6465078636019758},
  {"x":40,"y":1.9040041688426101}
 ]},{"key":"Stream #1","values":[
  {"x":0,"y":0.17426994759671852},
  {"x":1,"y":0.10907499905207074},
  {"x":2,"y":0.10435252778995735},
  {"x":3,"y":0.12619510522351818},
  {"x":4,"y":0.18649217576614804},
  {"x":5,"y":0.18443306535741213},
  {"x":6,"y":0.3777703694326517},
  {"x":7,"y":2.0217406217331124},
  {"x":8,"y":1.6460467361289448},
  {"x":9,"y":0.27637711590172165},
  {"x":10,"y":0.198215584506859},
  {"x":11,"y":0.4004557998016823},
  {"x":12,"y":1.0247250727963602},
  {"x":13,"y":2.0843574501067437},
  {"x":14,"y":2.905857836386078},
  {"x":15,"y":2.6005647975393367},
  {"x":16,"y":1.5810196661102656},
  {"x":17,"y":0.6686311036976872},
  {"x":18,"y":0.24740221938316848},
  {"x":19,"y":0.18911969272630683},
  {"x":20,"y":0.1425571773266894},
  {"x":21,"y":0.11190958629159675},
  {"x":22,"y":0.12860216397113625},
  {"x":23,"y":0.17270310562174815},
  {"x":24,"y":0.14561326892569426},
  {"x":25,"y":0.15468589134148195},
  {"x":26,"y":0.196300325696928},
  {"x":27,"y":0.12118193006162786},
  {"x":28,"y":0.1831280804553052},
  {"x":29,"y":0.18270541067403961},
  {"x":30,"y":0.19086790078401172},
  {"x":31,"y":0.15192921704834383},
  {"x":32,"y":0.14421553394637374},
  {"x":33,"y":0.13390583368632358},
  {"x":34,"y":0.1293233211328334},
  {"x":35,"y":0.1886456357493779},
  {"x":36,"y":0.13139777506605704},
  {"x":37,"y":0.11170526366555747},
  {"x":38,"y":0.14239031566724206},
  {"x":39,"y":0.11818122725007174},
  {"x":40,"y":0.12077580185646089}
 ]},{"key":"Stream #2","values":[
  {"x":0,"y":1.471846920511301},
  {"x":1,"y":2.8635730740336283},
  {"x":2,"y":0.1807350063665113},
  {"x":3,"y":0.1312445606782827},
  {"x":4,"y":0.14595662951702215},
  {"x":5,"y":0.25345667757071944},
  {"x":6,"y":1.681610490109687},
  {"x":7,"y":4.003584708765116},
  {"x":8,"y":1.2059311924153562},
  {"x":9,"y":0.9957121406657582},
  {"x":10,"y":1.1137190676588569},
  {"x":11,"y":1.1599930566049557},
  {"x":12,"y":0.9822084432919056},
  {"x":13,"y":0.7090343360228986},
  {"x":14,"y":0.4667308209714948},
  {"x":15,"y":0.3484988495410293},
  {"x":16,"y":0.23859373234594328},
  {"x":17,"y":0.1480619616245796},
  {"x":18,"y":0.19800772466465164},
  {"x":19,"y":0.10705030343081774},
  {"x":20,"y":0.1431810013595271},
  {"x":21,"y":0.18318093987617048},
  {"x":22,"y":0.10239602637228065},
  {"x":23,"y":0.12065693419532393},
  {"x":24,"y":0.10003387292829696},
  {"x":25,"y":0.15916390690992038},
  {"x":26,"y":0.15227389945671005},
  {"x":27,"y":0.1899390225921103},
  {"x":28,"y":0.18514730614271888},
  {"x":29,"y":0.16024815842184467},
  {"x":30,"y":0.13480139514028672},
  {"x":31,"y":0.1783542272146158},
  {"x":32,"y":0.15965861459525177},
  {"x":33,"y":0.1642077190994105},
  {"x":34,"y":0.1657098856135402},
  {"x":35,"y":0.19205326932283684},
  {"x":36,"y":0.12144715851166372},
  {"x":37,"y":0.13237318849423438},
  {"x":38,"y":0.1762539956553613},
  {"x":39,"y":0.1525422773161735},
  {"x":40,"y":0.19945005704289856}
 ]}
];

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
      .transitionDuration(350)
      .reduceXTicks(true)
      .rotateLabels(0)
      .showControls(true)
      .groupSpacing(0.1);
   
    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
    d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(data).call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});

//Generate some nice data.
function exampleData() {
  return stream_layers(3,10+Math.random()*100,.1).map(function(data, i) {
    return {
      key: 'Stream #' + i,
      values: data
    };
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
<div id="chart1">
  <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
</div>
```